# Mono.data.sqlite and System.data.sqlite conflict in Running Mono in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mono, system.data.sqlite

The assemblies/libraries Mono.data.sqlite and System.data.sqlite conflict in Running Mono in VS2010...I have downloaded "sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.83.0.exe" from the official website of sqlite.org...Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

You should not use System.Data.SQLite if your application targets Mono. That assembly is a mixed mode module (via C++/CLI), which is Windows only. The conflict is expected, and you have to make a change.

You can find more details from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki